# Exception while running dll made from jar in .NET

Tags: java, c++, dll

I have a requirement wherein i have to make dll using IKVM from jar file.
This jar file contains code related to java.security APIs i.e. Signing and verifying files.
When i am trying to execute this dll in my .net framework environment.

The exception which I am getting while signing process is :

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS12 not found
        at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:616)
```

My code where it is failing is :

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath);
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(fileInputStream, password);
```

While verifying also my code is failing at the below part:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(KeyFilePath);
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.
                    getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory
                    .generateCertificate(inputStream);
```

As per my understanding PKCS12 and X.509 is native to java and won't work directly.
Please let me know if my understanding is correct and help me resolving it.

Comment: Mixing Java, C++ and .Net? Ouch. You better have a very good reason for such a design. That said, PKCS12 and X.509 are language-independent standards, not Java specific. You should be able to find an equivalent .Net class.

Comment: Thnks MSalters for your reply.
Right that lot of mixing is there but this is as per requirement :).
No option of changing anything now....just need to run the DLL without making any changes in java code.